# Codeigniter: No error but it won't insert data to database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Model:

```
function insertMonths($dr){
    $cus = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM purchase WHERE status=1 AND dr_no='$dr'");
    return $cus->row();
    $start = (new DateTime($cus->date_sold))->modify('+1 month');
    $end = (new DateTime($cust->due_date))->modify('+1 month');
    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
    $period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM duedate WHERE dr_no='$dr'");
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return false;
    }else{
        foreach ($period as $dt) {
          $datas = array(
             'cust_id' => $cust->cust_id ,
             'mi' => $dt->format("Y-m-d") ,
             'amount' => $cust->monthly_instlmnt,
             'dr_no' => $dr,
             'payment' => $cust->monthly_instlmnt
             );
          $this->db->insert('duedate', $datas);
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
function ledger($id, $dr){
    $this->load->view('layout/header');
    $data['cust_data'] = $this->m->getData($id);
    $datar['mos'] = $this->m->insertMonths($dr);
    $this->load->view('receivables/ledger', $data, $datar);
    $this->load->view('layout/footer');
}
```

Botton js code that links to ledger:

```
'<td><a href="<?php echo base_url().'Receivables/ledger/';?>'+data[i].cust_id+'/'+data[i].dr_no+'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">View</button></a></td>'
```

I want it to add `$datas` into table `duedate` when I enter link `ledger/id/dr` with conditions if there is duplicate data it won't add.
But the problem is it won't add eventhough there is no duplicate data.

Comment: you are returning value from this line` return $cus->row();`. so the later code is not executed. please check that

Comment: When you write "no errors", did you check both the console and the error logs (on your server)?

Comment: PHP wont execute lines below `return $cus->row();`  this line

Comment: why don't you use code igniter query builder? As it is,  you can be hacked via sql injection

Comment: Thank you all for the advice. I got it right.

Comment: Not sure if you noticed by you used `cust` instead of `cus` in some places

Comment: Please use qb or escape your inputs: `$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM purchase WHERE status=1 AND dr_no='$dr'")` to `$this->db->where('dr_no', $dr); $this->db->where('status', 1); $this->db->get('purchase');` OR `$this->db->get_where('purchase', array('status' => 1, 'dr_no' => $dr));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have a `return` statement on line 2 of your function?

```
$cus = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM purchase WHERE status=1 AND dr_no='$dr'");
return $cus->row();
```

If you neglected that, it won't go to your insert query since you already commanded the function to return.

---

Remove this (**On line 2 of your function**)

```
return $cus->row();
```

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: I'm sorry but i think i just answered the question from my comprehension. I thought He's asking why the data won't go through the database even though there is no error. But anyway thanks. I'm just a beginner here.

Comment: Point OP whats error and suggest OP with a solution. As many of us see its like comment.